# How can I get the position of the last page of a viewpager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I want to inflate another layout to an activity that has a viewpager on the last page. It's like a quiz wherein after all answering the questions (where in the sets of question and answer is in the layout inflated in the viewpager) I want to inflate another layout on the last part of my viewpager and display a message like "Thank you for taking a quiz!", for debugging purposes, I've tried writing some condition on the `public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position)` method like this

```
if (position == getCount()){ //get count returns the number of pagesize
  //do some layout inflating here
}
```

to debug, I use Toast message to show the current page, but it does not show something if I swipe the viewpager on the very last page, what is the right way to fix that?

**UPDATED CODE**

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) survey.findViewById(R.id.pagersurvey);


        Toast.makeText(survey, "Page " + mPager.getCurrentItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) survey
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_survey, null);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);
        return layout;
}
```

I want every slide/page shows a toast message of it's current page BUT, the last page of the viewpager, does not show any toast message.

Answer (score 1):

Create a listener and set it on your viewpager:

```
 /**
     * Get the current view position from the ViewPager by
     * extending SimpleOnPageChangeListener class and adding your method
     */
    public class DetailOnPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {

        private int currentPage;

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;
        }

        public final int getCurrentPage() {
            return currentPage;
        }
    }
```

or just try this line of code

```
mViewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

source and more info from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem%28%29

Comment: The last page isn't returning anything using .getCurrentItem(); but the other returns

Answer (score 0):

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(survey, "Page " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) survey
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = R.layout.normalView;
        if(position==getCount)
            resID = R.layout.SpecificView;

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
}
```

Comment: Whenever I'm going to the last page of my viewpager, it does not display a position to a toast message, any idea why?

Comment: post your code so we can check and let you know about wrong doing.

Comment: mPager.getCurrentItem() is causing you problem use position. it should solve your problem

Comment: Same error sir. Still I can't get the position of the last slide/page.